# How to slice a pandas.DatetimeIndex?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

What is the best way to get dates between, say, `'2019-01-08'` and `'2019-01-16'`, from the `pandas.DatetimeIndex` object `dti` as constructed below? Ideally, some concise syntax like `dti['2019-01-08':'2019-01-16']`?

```
import pandas as pd
dti = pd.bdate_range(start='2019-01-01', end='2019-02-15')

DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04',
               '2019-01-07', '2019-01-08', '2019-01-09', '2019-01-10',
               '2019-01-11', '2019-01-14', '2019-01-15', '2019-01-16',
               '2019-01-17', '2019-01-18', '2019-01-21', '2019-01-22',
               '2019-01-23', '2019-01-24', '2019-01-25', '2019-01-28',
               '2019-01-29', '2019-01-30', '2019-01-31', '2019-02-01',
               '2019-02-04', '2019-02-05', '2019-02-06', '2019-02-07',
               '2019-02-08', '2019-02-11', '2019-02-12', '2019-02-13',
               '2019-02-14', '2019-02-15'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the source code for [`DatetimeIndex.__getitem__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.2/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py#L1219-L1228) method, the individual dates in a `DatetimeIndex` is stored in a `DatetimeArray`. To support slicing, you need to get the integer indices of the start and stop date in that array. I suggest that you file a feature request with the pandas development team.

Meanwhile, you can monkey-patch it in:

```
from pandas.core.indexes.datetimes import DatetimeIndex

__old_getitem = DatetimeIndex.__getitem__

def __new_getitem(index, key):
    if isinstance(key, slice):
        _key = index.slice_indexer(key.start, key.stop, key.step)
    else:
        _key = key

    return __old_getitem(index, _key)

DatetimeIndex.__getitem__ = __new_getitem

# Now you can slice
dti['2019-01-08':'2019-01-16':4]
```

Comment: Is there any way to slice it directly, instead of convert to `Series` and then convert back to `DatetimeIndex`. I am still going to use it as index after slicing.

Comment: Regarding your question: I am just using `bdate_range` as a convenience to create a `DatetimeIndex` object. In reality, the `DatetimeIndex` object could be created in various ways.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it with the [slice_indexer for DateTimeIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.3/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.slice_indexer.html)

`pandas.DateTimeIndex.slice_indexer(start, stop, step, [...])`

It returns the indexes of the datetime items so you can pass it to dti

Example:

```
dti[dti.slice_indexer("2019-01-07", "2019-01-17")]
```